# Converting latitude and longitude to decimal values

Tags: javascript, regex, geolocation, gps, geocoding

I have GPS information presented in the form:

36°57'9" N 110°4'21" W

I can use the [javascript functions of Chris Veness](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to convert degrees, minutes and seconds to numeric degrees, but first need to parse the GPS info into the individual latitude and longitude strings (with NSEW suffixes). I have read related posts on stackoverflow, but am not a regex expert (nor a programmer) and need some help with the parsing function.  What's the best way to parse this string into latitude and longitude for use in the conversion function?

The result of all this will be a Web link that one can click on to see a Google map representation of location.

Comment: What exactly is the format of the output you are looking for? Is it something like: "36 57 9 N" and "110 4 21 W" for the input you have given? Does the input always come in this form?

Comment: For the inputs I've shown, I'd expect the output to be two values:
36.95250
-110.07250
And yes, the input is always in this form.

Comment: That should read, "two values: 36.95250 and -110.07250 (without the "and" of course). Sorry.

Answer (score 75):

To parse your input use the following.

```
function ParseDMS(input) {
    var parts = input.split(/[^\d\w]+/);
    var lat = ConvertDMSToDD(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
    var lng = ConvertDMSToDD(parts[4], parts[5], parts[6], parts[7]);
}
```

The following will convert your DMS to DD

```
function ConvertDMSToDD(degrees, minutes, seconds, direction) {
    var dd = degrees + minutes/60 + seconds/(60*60);

    if (direction == "S" || direction == "W") {
        dd = dd * -1;
    } // Don't do anything for N or E
    return dd;
}
```

So your input would produce the following:

```
36°57'9" N  = 36.9525000
110°4'21" W = -110.0725000
```

Decimal coordinates can be fed into google maps to get points via `GLatLng(lat, lng)` ([Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLng))

Comment: Perhaps a little better: var parts = input.split(/[^\d\w]+/). Adjust offsets by -1.

Comment: That should work!  I'll give it a try tonight. Thanks to all who responded.  This site is the best!

Comment: I'm dealing with this issue to, though have to cater for some alternative HMS representations: `2°28’14”N`, `50 44.63N`, `S 038° 18.429’`.  I only show these here in case others need to think about them too.

Comment: ParseDMS("36°57'9\" N") gives me 360.95. I don't understand why. Besides, 36°57'9.0" N would not work.

Comment: You're doing input.split() on the lat/long, so you're working with strings, so you should wrap degrees, minutes and seconds in parseInt() before attempting arithmetic operations on them.
It was causing weird results for me.

Comment: if you know beforehand that 60*60 is 3600 why to compute?

Comment: second unit can contain real number e.g. N44°34'59.2

Comment: you'll get some f***** up results if you don't wrap it in floats. 
`var dd = parseFloat(degrees) + parseFloat(minutes) / 60 + parseFloat(seconds) / (60 * 60);`

Answer (score 20):

Corrected the above functions and made the output an object.

```
function ParseDMS(input) {
    var parts = input.split(/[^\d\w\.]+/);    
    var lat = ConvertDMSToDD(parts[0], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4]);
    var lng = ConvertDMSToDD(parts[5], parts[7], parts[8], parts[9]);

    return {
        Latitude : lat,
        Longitude: lng,
        Position : lat + ',' + lng
    }
}


function ConvertDMSToDD(degrees, minutes, seconds, direction) {   
    var dd = Number(degrees) + Number(minutes)/60 + Number(seconds)/(60*60);

    if (direction == "S" || direction == "W") {
        dd = dd * -1;
    } // Don't do anything for N or E
    return dd;
}
```

Comment: if you know beforehand that 60*60 is 3600 why to compute?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira It can be easier to quickly understand. Many people might realize there are 60 seconds in a minute and 60 minutes in an hour/degree, but realizing there are 3600 seconds in an hour/degree is slightly less obvious.

Answer (score 11):

My tweaked version coerces the string parts into Numbers so that they can actually be added together rather than concatenated. It also handles decimal values which are common for the Seconds component:

```
function ParseDMS(input) {
    var parts = input.split(/[^\d\w\.]+/);
    var lat = ConvertDMSToDD(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
    var lng = ConvertDMSToDD(parts[4], parts[5], parts[6], parts[7]);
}
```

The following will convert your DMS to DD

```
function ConvertDMSToDD(degrees, minutes, seconds, direction) {
    var dd = Number(degrees) + Number(minutes)/60 + Number(seconds)/(60*60);

    if (direction == "S" || direction == "W") {
        dd = dd * -1;
    } // Don't do anything for N or E
    return dd;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

here is my take on this:

```
function parse_gps( input ) {

if( input.indexOf( 'N' ) == -1 && input.indexOf( 'S' ) == -1 &&
    input.indexOf( 'W' ) == -1 && input.indexOf( 'E' ) == -1 ) {
    return input.split(',');
}

var parts = input.split(/[°'"]+/).join(' ').split(/[^\w\S]+/);

var directions = [];
var coords = [];
var dd = 0;
var pow = 0;

for( i in parts ) {

    // we end on a direction
    if( isNaN( parts[i] ) ) {

        var _float = parseFloat( parts[i] );

        var direction = parts[i];

        if( !isNaN(_float ) ) {
            dd += ( _float / Math.pow( 60, pow++ ) );
            direction = parts[i].replace( _float, '' );
        }

        direction = direction[0];

        if( direction == 'S' || direction == 'W' )
            dd *= -1;

        directions[ directions.length ] = direction;

        coords[ coords.length ] = dd;
        dd = pow = 0;

    } else {

        dd += ( parseFloat(parts[i]) / Math.pow( 60, pow++ ) );

    }

}

if( directions[0] == 'W' || directions[0] == 'E' ) {
    var tmp = coords[0];
    coords[0] = coords[1];
    coords[1] = tmp;
}

return coords;
```

}

This function doesn't handle all types of lat / long types, but it handles the following formats:

```
-31,2222,21.99999
-31 13 13 13.75S, -31 13 13 13.75W
-31 13 13 13.75S -31 13 13 13.75W
-31 13 13 13.75W -31 13.75S
36°57'9" N 110°4'21" W
110°4'21" W 36°57'9"N
```

Which is what i needed.

Comment: Far better than other solutions :-)

Comment: I also really appreciate this version.

Comment: Thanks, this should be the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

I got some NaN's on this function and needed to do this (don't ask me why)

```
function ConvertDMSToDD(days, minutes, seconds, direction) {
    var dd = days + (minutes/60) + seconds/(60*60);
    dd = parseFloat(dd);
    if (direction == "S" || direction == "W") {
        dd *= -1;
    } // Don't do anything for N or E
    return dd;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used **\d+(\,\d+)** and **\d+(.\d+)** because can have float numbers

My final function:

```
 convertDMSToDD: function (dms) {
     let parts = dms.split(/[^\d+(\,\d+)\d+(\.\d+)?\w]+/);
     let degrees = parseFloat(parts[0]);
     let minutes = parseFloat(parts[1]);
     let seconds = parseFloat(parts[2].replace(',','.'));
     let direction = parts[3];

     console.log('degrees: '+degrees)
     console.log('minutes: '+minutes)
     console.log('seconds: '+seconds)
     console.log('direction: '+direction)

     let dd = degrees + minutes / 60 + seconds / (60 * 60);

     if (direction == 'S' || direction == 'W') {
       dd = dd * -1;
     } // Don't do anything for N or E
     return dd;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Joe, the script you've mentioned already did what do you want. With it you can convert lat and long and put it into link to see location in Google map:

```
var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&q=&vps=3&jsv=166d&sll=" + lat.parseDeg() + "," + longt.parseDeg()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Shannon Antonio Black's regex pattern (above), my solution is:

```js
function convertLatLong(input) {

if(!( input.toUpperCase() != input.toLowerCase()) ) {   // if geodirection abbr. isn't exist, it should be already decimal notation
    return `${input}:the coordinate already seems as decimal`
}
const parts = input.split(/[°'"]+/).join(' ').split(/[^\w\S]+/); // thanks to Shannon Antonio Black for regEx patterns 
const geoLetters = parts.filter(el=> !(+el) ) 
const coordNumber = parts.filter(n=>(+n)).map(nr=>+nr)
const latNumber = coordNumber.slice(0,(coordNumber.length/2))
const longNumber = coordNumber.slice((coordNumber.length/2))
const reducer = function(acc,coord,curInd){
   return acc + (coord/Math.pow( 60, curInd++ ))
}
let latDec = latNumber.reduce(reducer)
let longDec = longNumber.reduce(reducer)

if(geoLetters[0].toUpperCase()==='S') latDec = -latDec // if the geodirection is S or W, decimal notation should start with minus
if(geoLetters[1].toUpperCase()==='W') longDec= -longDec 

const dec= [{
    ltCoord: latDec,
    geoLet:geoLetters[0]
},
{
    longCoord: longDec,
    geoLet: geoLetters[1]
}]

return dec
}
```

I think that is more simplified version with EC6

Answer (score 0):

```js
function convertRawCoordinatesIntoDecimal(input) {
    let grade = parseInt(input.substring(0, input.indexOf("°")));
    let rest = input.substring(input.indexOf("°") + 1);
    let minutes = parseInt(rest.substring(0, rest.indexOf("'")));
    let seconds = parseInt(rest.substring(rest.indexOf("'") + 1).split('"')[0]);
    return grade + (minutes + seconds / 60) / 60;
}

function getCoordinates(input) {
    let parts = input.split(" "); //element 0 is N and element 2 is W coordinates
    return {
        [parts[1]]: convertRawCoordinatesIntoDecimal(parts[0]),
        [parts[3]]: convertRawCoordinatesIntoDecimal(parts[2])
    };
}

let input = `36°57'9" N 110°4'21" W`; //a test input
console.log(getCoordinates(input));
```

Result:

```
{
  "N": 36.9525,
  "W": 110.0725
}
```

Explanation:

- we split by `" "`, getting an array of strings of four elements
- element 1 will be the name of the first coordinate and element 3 will be the name of the second coordinate
- element 0 will be the value of the first coordinate and element 2 will be the value of the second coordinate
- we dissect the elements into `grade`, `minutes` and `seconds` respectively, all numerical values
- the formula is `grade + (minutes + seconds / 60) / 60`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for yet another algorithm, but I needed to run this on user-provided input, so I need to check whether it matches the desired format at all. To achieve this, I’m using a regexp on the whole string.

```js
const lonLatRegexp = (() => {
    const number = `[-\u2212]?\\s*\\d+([.,]\\d+)?`;

    const getCoordinate = (n: number) => (
        `(` +
            `(?<hemispherePrefix${n}>[NWSE])` +
        `)?(` +
            `(?<degrees${n}>${number})` +
            `(\\s*[°]\\s*|\\s*deg\\s*|\\s+|$|(?!\\d))` +
        `)(` +
            `(?<minutes${n}>${number})` +
            `(\\s*['\u2032\u2019]\\s*)` +
        `)?(` +
            `(?<seconds${n}>${number})` +
            `(\\s*["\u2033\u201d]\\s*)` +
        `)?(` +
            `(?<hemisphereSuffix${n}>[NWSE])` +
        `)?`
    );

    const coords = (
        `(geo\\s*:\\s*)?` +
        `\\s*` +
        getCoordinate(1) +
        `(?<separator>\\s*[,;]\\s*|\\s+)` +
        getCoordinate(2) +
        `(\\?z=(?<zoom>\\d+))?`
    );

    return new RegExp(`^\\s*${coords}\\s*$`, "i");
})();

export function matchLonLat(query: string): (Point & { zoom?: number }) | undefined {
    const m = lonLatRegexp.exec(query);

    const prepareNumber = (str: string) => Number(str.replace(",", ".").replace("\u2212", "-").replace(/\s+/, ""));
    const prepareCoords = (deg: string, min: string | undefined, sec: string | undefined, hem: string | undefined) => {
        const degrees = prepareNumber(deg);
        const result = Math.abs(degrees) + (min ? prepareNumber(min) / 60 : 0) + (sec ? prepareNumber(sec) / 3600 : 0);
        return result * (degrees < 0 ? -1 : 1) * (hem && ["s", "S", "w", "W"].includes(hem) ? -1 : 1);
    };

    if (m) {
        const { hemispherePrefix1, degrees1, minutes1, seconds1, hemisphereSuffix1, separator, hemispherePrefix2, degrees2, minutes2, seconds2, hemisphereSuffix2, zoom } = m.groups!;

        let hemisphere1: string | undefined = undefined, hemisphere2: string | undefined = undefined;
        if (hemispherePrefix1 && !hemisphereSuffix1 && hemispherePrefix2 && !hemisphereSuffix2) {
            [hemisphere1, hemisphere2] = [hemispherePrefix1, hemispherePrefix2];
        } else if (!hemispherePrefix1 && hemisphereSuffix1 && !hemispherePrefix2 && hemisphereSuffix2) {
            [hemisphere1, hemisphere2] = [hemisphereSuffix1, hemisphereSuffix2];
        } else if (hemispherePrefix1 && hemisphereSuffix1 && !hemispherePrefix2 && !hemisphereSuffix2 && !separator.trim()) {
            // Coordinate 2 has a hemisphere prefix, but because the two coordinates are separated by whitespace only, it was matched as a coordinate 1 suffix
            [hemisphere1, hemisphere2] = [hemispherePrefix1, hemisphereSuffix1];
        } else if (hemispherePrefix1 || hemisphereSuffix1 || hemispherePrefix2 || hemisphereSuffix2) {
            // Unsupported combination of hemisphere prefixes/suffixes
            return undefined;
        } // else: no hemispheres specified

        const coordinate1 = prepareCoords(degrees1, minutes1, seconds1, hemisphere1);
        const coordinate2 = prepareCoords(degrees2, minutes2, seconds2, hemisphere2);
        const zoomNumber = zoom ? Number(zoom) : undefined;
        const zoomObj = zoomNumber != null && isFinite(zoomNumber) ? { zoom: zoomNumber } : {};

        // Handle cases where lat/lon are switched
        if ([undefined, "n", "N", "s", "S"].includes(hemisphere1) && [undefined, "w", "W", "e", "E"].includes(hemisphere2)) {
            return { lat: coordinate1, lon: coordinate2, ...zoomObj };
        } else if ((["w", "W", "e", "E"] as Array<string | undefined>).includes(hemisphere1) && [undefined, "n", "N", "s", "S"].includes(hemisphere2)) {
            return { lat: coordinate2, lon: coordinate1, ...zoomObj };
        }
    }
}


// Tests
test("matchLonLat", () => {
    // Simple coordinates
    expect(matchLonLat("1.234,2.345")).toEqual({ lat: 1.234, lon: 2.345 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1.234,2.345")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: 2.345 });
    expect(matchLonLat("1.234,-2.345")).toEqual({ lat: 1.234, lon: -2.345 });

    // Integers
    expect(matchLonLat("1,2")).toEqual({ lat: 1, lon: 2 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1,2")).toEqual({ lat: -1, lon: 2 });
    expect(matchLonLat("1,-2")).toEqual({ lat: 1, lon: -2 });

    // With unicode minus
    expect(matchLonLat("−1.234,2.345")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: 2.345 });
    expect(matchLonLat("1.234,−2.345")).toEqual({ lat: 1.234, lon: -2.345 });

    // With spaces
    expect(matchLonLat("  -  1.234  ,  -  2.345  ")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345 });

    // With different separators
    expect(matchLonLat("-1.234;-2.345")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1.234 -2.345")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345 });

    // Using decimal comma
    expect(matchLonLat("-1,234,-2,345")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1,234;-2,345")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1,234 -2,345")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345 });

    // Geo URI
    expect(matchLonLat("geo:-1.234,-2.345")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345 });
    expect(matchLonLat("geo:-1.234,-2.345?z=10")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345, zoom: 10 });

    // With degree sign
    expect(matchLonLat("-1.234° -2.345°")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1.234 ° -2.345 °")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1.234 °, -2.345 °")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345 });

    // With "deg"
    expect(matchLonLat("-1.234deg -2.345deg")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1.234 deg -2.345 deg")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1.234 deg, -2.345 deg")).toEqual({ lat: -1.234, lon: -2.345 });

    // With minutes
    expect(matchLonLat("-1° 24' -2° 36'")).toEqual({ lat: -1.4, lon: -2.6 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1° 24', -2° 36'")).toEqual({ lat: -1.4, lon: -2.6 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1 ° 24 ' -2 ° 36 '")).toEqual({ lat: -1.4, lon: -2.6 });

    // With unicode minute sign
    expect(matchLonLat("-1deg 24′ -2deg 36′")).toEqual({ lat: -1.4, lon: -2.6 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1deg 24′, -2deg 36′")).toEqual({ lat: -1.4, lon: -2.6 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1 deg 24 ′ -2 deg 36 ′")).toEqual({ lat: -1.4, lon: -2.6 });

    // With seconds
    expect(matchLonLat("-1° 24' 36\" -2° 36' 72\"")).toEqual({ lat: -1.41, lon: -2.62 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1° 24' 36\", -2° 36' 72\"")).toEqual({ lat: -1.41, lon: -2.62 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1 ° 24 ' 36 \" -2 ° 36 ' 72 \"")).toEqual({ lat: -1.41, lon: -2.62 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1° 36\" -2° 72\"")).toEqual({ lat: -1.01, lon: -2.02 });

    // With unicode second sign
    expect(matchLonLat("-1deg 24′ 36″ -2deg 36′ 72″")).toEqual({ lat: -1.41, lon: -2.62 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1deg 24′ 36″, -2deg 36′ 72″")).toEqual({ lat: -1.41, lon: -2.62 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1 deg 24 ′ 36 ″ -2 deg 36 ′ 72 ″")).toEqual({ lat: -1.41, lon: -2.62 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1deg 36″ -2deg 72″")).toEqual({ lat: -1.01, lon: -2.02 });

    // With unicode quote signs
    expect(matchLonLat("-1deg 24’ 36” -2deg 36’ 72”")).toEqual({ lat: -1.41, lon: -2.62 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1deg 24’ 36”, -2deg 36’ 72”")).toEqual({ lat: -1.41, lon: -2.62 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1 deg 24 ’ 36 ” -2 deg 36 ’ 72 ”")).toEqual({ lat: -1.41, lon: -2.62 });
    expect(matchLonLat("-1deg 36” -2deg 72”")).toEqual({ lat: -1.01, lon: -2.02 });

    // Other hemisphere
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' N 2° 36' E")).toEqual({ lat: 1.4, lon: 2.6 });
    expect(matchLonLat("N 1° 24' E 2° 36'")).toEqual({ lat: 1.4, lon: 2.6 });
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' S 2° 36' E")).toEqual({ lat: -1.4, lon: 2.6 });
    expect(matchLonLat("S 1° 24' E 2° 36'")).toEqual({ lat: -1.4, lon: 2.6 });
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' N 2° 36' W")).toEqual({ lat: 1.4, lon: -2.6 });
    expect(matchLonLat("N 1° 24' W 2° 36'")).toEqual({ lat: 1.4, lon: -2.6 });
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' s 2° 36' w")).toEqual({ lat: -1.4, lon: -2.6 });
    expect(matchLonLat("s 1° 24' w 2° 36'")).toEqual({ lat: -1.4, lon: -2.6 });

    // Switch lon/lat
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' E 2° 36' N")).toEqual({ lat: 2.6, lon: 1.4 });
    expect(matchLonLat("E 1° 24' N 2° 36'")).toEqual({ lat: 2.6, lon: 1.4 });
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' E 2° 36' S")).toEqual({ lat: -2.6, lon: 1.4 });
    expect(matchLonLat("E 1° 24' S 2° 36'")).toEqual({ lat: -2.6, lon: 1.4 });
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' W 2° 36' N")).toEqual({ lat: 2.6, lon: -1.4 });
    expect(matchLonLat("W 1° 24' N 2° 36'")).toEqual({ lat: 2.6, lon: -1.4 });
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' W 2° 36' S")).toEqual({ lat: -2.6, lon: -1.4 });
    expect(matchLonLat("W 1° 24' S 2° 36'")).toEqual({ lat: -2.6, lon: -1.4 });

    // Practical examples
    expect(matchLonLat("N 53°53’42.8928” E 10°44’13.4844”")).toEqual({ lat: 53.895248, lon: 10.737079 }); // Park4night
    expect(matchLonLat("53°53'42.8928\"N 10°44'13.4844\"E")).toEqual({ lat: 53.895248, lon: 10.737079 }); // Google Maps

    // Invalid lon/lat combination
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' N 2° 36' N")).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' E 2° 36' E")).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' S 2° 36' S")).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' W 2° 36' W")).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' N 2° 36' S")).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' S 2° 36' N")).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' W 2° 36' E")).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' E 2° 36' W")).toEqual(undefined);

    // Invalid hemisphere prefix/suffix combination
    expect(matchLonLat("N 1° 24' 2° 36'")).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' E 2° 36'")).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' 2° 36' E")).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(matchLonLat("N 1° 24' E 2° 36' E")).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(matchLonLat("N 1° 24' 2° 36' E")).toEqual(undefined);
    expect(matchLonLat("1° 24' E N 2° 36'")).toEqual(undefined);
});
```

My code supports the following formats (and combinations thereof and variants with additional white spaces):

- `-1.234,-2.345`
- `geo:-1.234,-2.345`
- `geo:-1.234,-2.345?z=10`
- `-1.234;-2.345` (semicolon separator)
- `-1.234 -2.345` (space separator)
- `-1,234 -2,345` (decimal comma)
- `−1.234,−2.345` (Unicode minus)
- `-1.234°, -2.345°`
- `1° 23', 2° 34'`
- `1° 23' 45.67", 2° 34' 56.78"`
- `1 deg 23' 45.67", 2 deg 34' 56.78"`
- `1° 45.67", 2° 56.78"` (seconds but no minutes)
- `1° 23′ 45.67″, 2° 34′ 56.78″` (Unicode minutes and seconds)
- `1° 23’ 45.67”, 2° 34’ 56.78”` (Unicode quotes for minutes and seconds)
- `-1° 23' 45.67", -2° 34' 56.78"`
- `1° 23' 45.67" S, 2° 34' 56.78" W` (hemisphere suffix)
- `S 1° 23' 45.67", W 2° 34' 56.78"` (hemisphere prefix)
- `2° 34' 56.78" W 1° 23' 45.67" S` (latitude/longitude switched)

If the input has an invalid format, undefined is returned.