# Can Google Maps plot points based on Hours Minutes Seconds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gps, degrees

I'm trying to plot out GPS data that is given to me in Hour Minute Second degree format. Will GLatLng take it in this form or do I need to convert it first. Having a hard time finding anything on the internet about this. If it can take it in this format an example would be much appreciated.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140189/converting-latitude-and-longitude-to-decimal-values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know it does not accept that format, but its really easy to convert it, just do the math:

```
var = hour+(((minute*60)+(second))/3600);
```

Comment: Thanks but I am having a hard time with the Latitude as this formula doesn't account for the earth not being perfectly spherical. I'm also having a hard time finding a formula that compensates for this. Precision is of the up most importance on this project.

Comment: @Serhiy - This formula perfectly converts a coordinate from 'Degree-Minute-Second' format to 'Decimal Degrees' format. The shape of the earth doesn't affect this conversion, though it does affect things like calculating distances

Comment: @Chris B - I see... thanks for the explanation... I think I was having some calculation issues either with PHP or JS... they've been resolved for the most part.