# GPS Coordinates and Google API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a set of GPS Cordniates like so:

```
N: 49 33 40, W: 101 26 21
```

I need to give these to google maps to find the location. - and idea on how? I am looking through [Google Maps API 3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) docs and coming up empty handed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at reverse geocoding: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

An example query:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false
```

Answer (score 3):

Google maps api doesn't handle DMS format. You'll have to convert it first to decimal values and then use reverse geocoding as Rohit suggested.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751965/can-google-maps-plot-points-based-on-hours-minutes-seconds) and [here](http://www.gps-coordinates.net/) for the transformation

P.S. The first link is from stackoverflow that's why I don't include the code. If an upvote is appropriate, then it should go to the author of that answer and not to me.