# Converting geo coordinates Format

Tags: node.js, geocoding

I am asked to show a gps device on a Google Map. I have written a listener and the format looks something like this

```
1724.1543,N,07822.4276,E
```

How can I convert these into degrees, minutes and seconds, with a format as below?

```
17.241543,78.224276
```

Apparently Google Maps recognizes lat lng in the above format only.

My listener is written in Node.js, so I'm seeking a JavaScript approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting latitude and longitude to decimal values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140189/converting-latitude-and-longitude-to-decimal-values)

Answer (score 0):

javascript way to convert lat and long to degree,minute and second is as follows:

//to convert pass lat or long to this function

```
function DECtoDMS(dd)
{
    var vars  = dd.split('.');
    var deg   = vars[0];
    var tempma = "0."+vars[1];
    tempma = tempma * 3600;
    var min = Math.floor(tempma / 60);
    var sec = tempma - (min * 60);
    return deg+"-"+min+"-"+sec;
}
```

//call the function

```
var inDeg  = DECtoDMS(72.8479400);
console.log(inDeg);
```