# Convert GPS Cordinates into Latitude Longitude?

Tags: google-maps, gps, latitude-longitude

I have the GPS String in our database, its received from the one of the GPS device. String is-

```
4956.7306,N,03621.2701,E
```

I am not too sure, string in which format. And how this can be show in degree formate.
I want to get Lattitude and Longitude from the above string which I have.
I also try to plot this co-ordinates on google map search bar on [Google Map](https://www.google.co.in/maps/), it's showing me the location and May be the lat-long is

> 22.7488455,75.8328085

I can't find the solution on the same , I want the latlong from the given GPS Co-Ordinates.

Please help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140189/converting-latitude-and-longitude-to-decimal-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140189/converting-latitude-and-longitude-to-decimal-values)

Comment: I think this is not the GPS Co-Ordinates. because  Co-Ordinates is a combination of degree's and minutes But here it not shows

Comment: @kmgkumar may be this will be 49 56.7306,N,03 621.2701,E. But I am not too sure how we can seprate this into degres like 36°57'9" N 110°4'21" W Blackkara suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt this just 49 56.7306,N,03 621.2701,E  ?

If you paste this into Google Maps it points to southern Africa.  Is that likely?

Comment: It's showing Location in Indore, India for me.
How this can be validate that this can be in proper formates and can be converted into Latitude and Longitude to plot marker on the map.

Comment: Also I have found the trick where I can able to plot on right location.

Comment: Also I have found the trick where I can able to plot on right location. Since my string is 4956.7306,N,03621.2701,E If I can modified this as 49 56.7306,036 21.2701. And then If search in google map) , It's giving right location. But main thing this should plot on google map like pass the latitude and longitude at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple. But this giving error as "Unexpected number". Obeiously its not lat long. Please help me that how can I achive this. Thanks